# Java game of pig score not counting?

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while, do-loops

I have the game of pig in java running, however, it seems that player one score keeps going past 100 even though i have multiple things in place to make sure it doesn't happen. player 2 won't go over 100, but player 1 will. What am i doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigDice {
    static int dice1 = 0;
    static int dice2 = 0;
    final int maxScore = 100;
    static int player1Score = 0;
    static int player2Score = 0;
    static int player1Turn = 0;
    static int player2Turn = 0;
    boolean game = true;
    static String input = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            while (player1Score < 100 || player2Score < 100) {
                do {

                    System.out.println("PLAYER 1's TURN");
                    System.out.println("Current score: " + player1Score);
                    System.out.println("Number of turns taken: " + player1Turn);
                    dice1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    System.out.println("You rolled a: " + dice1);
                    if (dice1 == 1) {
                        System.out.println("You lose a turn and no points rewarded");
                        System.out.println("Score: " + player1Score);
                        System.out.println("");
                        player1Turn++;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Would you like to roll again, or bank your points?");
                        System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'b' to bank.");
                        String input = sc.nextLine();
                        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                            player1Score += dice1;
                            player1Turn++;
                            System.out.println("Current player 1 score: " + player1Score);
                            System.out.println("");
                            break;
                        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && dice1 != 1 && player1Score < 100) {
                            player1Score += dice1;
                            player1Turn++;
                            System.out.println("Current player 1 score: " + player1Score);
                            System.out.println("");

                        }
                    }

                } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice1 != 1);
                dice1 = 0;
                if (player1Score >= 100) {
                    System.out.println("Player one wins");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            }
            do {
                System.out.println("PLAYER 2's TURN");
                System.out.println("Number of turns taken: " + player2Turn);
                System.out.println("Current score: " + player2Score);
                dice2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                System.out.println("You rolled a: " + dice2);
                if (dice2 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("You lose a turn and no points rewarded");
                    System.out.println("Score: " + player2Score);
                    player2Turn++;
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Would you like to roll again, or bank your points?");
                    System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'b' to bank.");
                    String input = sc.nextLine();
                    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                        player2Score = dice2 + player2Score;
                        player2Turn++;
                        System.out.println("Current player 2 score: " + player2Score);
                        System.out.println("");
                        break;
                    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && dice2 != 1 && player2Score < 100) {
                        player2Score += dice2;
                        player2Turn++;
                        System.out.println("Current player 2 score: " + player2Score);
                        System.out.println("");

                    }
                }

            } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice2 != 1);
            dice2 = 0;
            if (player2Score >= 100) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
                break;
            }

        } while (player1Score < 100 || player2Score < 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think `player1Score < 100 || player2Score < 100` should be `player1Score < 100 && player2Score < 100`

Comment: You should use a debugger. You should probably also extract some method from this wall of code

Comment: 1- I think it's not helping; 2- What happens if `player1` wins before `player2`s turn?

Comment: the game continues until player 2 reaches 100. so if player 1 win, player 2 goes

Comment: next time you should be more specific on whether you are talking about expected behaviour or current buggy behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a added an unnecessary `while` loop (the one after the first `do` loop), which makes the `break` not break of player 1 not break from the main loop

Here is the code with the while loop removed

```
public class PigDice {

  static int dice1 = 0;
  static int dice2 = 0;
  static int player1Score = 0;
  static int player2Score = 0;
  static int player1Turn = 0;
  static int player2Turn = 0;
  static String input = "";
  final int maxScore = 100;
  boolean game = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        do {

          System.out.println("PLAYER 1's TURN");
          System.out.println("Current score: " + player1Score);
          System.out.println("Number of turns taken: " + player1Turn);
          dice1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
          System.out.println("You rolled a: " + dice1);
          if (dice1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("You lose a turn and no points rewarded");
            System.out.println("Score: " + player1Score);
            System.out.println("");
            player1Turn++;
            break;
          } else {
            System.out.println("Would you like to roll again, or bank your points?");
            System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'b' to bank.");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
              player1Score += dice1;
              player1Turn++;
              System.out.println("Current player 1 score: " + player1Score);
              System.out.println("");
              break;
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && dice1 != 1
                       && player1Score < 100) {
              player1Score += dice1;
              player1Turn++;
              System.out.println("Current player 1 score: " + player1Score);
              System.out.println("");

            }
          }

        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice1 != 1);
        dice1 = 0;
        if (player1Score >= 100) {
          System.out.println("Player one wins");
          break;
        }


      do {
        System.out.println("PLAYER 2's TURN");
        System.out.println("Number of turns taken: " + player2Turn);
        System.out.println("Current score: " + player2Score);
        dice2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("You rolled a: " + dice2);
        if (dice2 == 1) {
          System.out.println("You lose a turn and no points rewarded");
          System.out.println("Score: " + player2Score);
          player2Turn++;
          System.out.println("");
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Would you like to roll again, or bank your points?");
          System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'b' to bank.");
          String input = sc.nextLine();
          if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            player2Score = dice2 + player2Score;
            player2Turn++;
            System.out.println("Current player 2 score: " + player2Score);
            System.out.println("");
            break;
          } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && dice2 != 1 && player2Score < 100) {
            player2Score += dice2;
            player2Turn++;
            System.out.println("Current player 2 score: " + player2Score);
            System.out.println("");

          }
        }

      } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice2 != 1);
      dice2 = 0;
      if (player2Score >= 100) {
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
        break;
      }

    } while (player1Score < 100 || player2Score < 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many meaningless loops&breaks.

Try to refactor your's code to something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Ankh Zet (ankhzet@gmail.com)
 */
public class Pig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Pig()).game();
    }

    class Player {

        int turnScore = 0;
        int totalScore = 0;

        String name;

        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random diceRoll = new Random();

    public void game() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

        Player player1 = new Player("Player 1");
        Player player2 = new Player("Player 2");

        Player next = player1;
        while (true) {
            int score = turn(next);

            if (score >= 100) {
                System.out.println(next.name.toUpperCase() + " WINS!");
                break;
            }

            if (next == player1)
                next = player2;
            else
                next = player1;
        }
    }

    enum Action {
        Roll, Hold;
    }

    int turn(Player player) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("It is " + player.name + "'s turn.");

        player.turnScore = 0;

        int dice;
        while ((dice = roll()) != 1) {
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice);

            player.turnScore += dice;

            System.out.println("Your turn score is " + player.turnScore);
            System.out.println("And your total score is " + player.totalScore);
            System.out.println("If you hold, " + player.turnScore + " points will be added to your total score.");

            if (takeInput() != Action.Roll)
                break;
        }

        if (dice == 1) {
            player.turnScore = 0;
            System.out.println("You rolled a 1");
            System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
        }

        player.totalScore += player.turnScore;
        System.out.println("Your total score is " + player.totalScore);

        return player.totalScore;
    }

    int roll() {
        return diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    Action takeInput() {
        String input;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
        } while (input.isEmpty());

        switch (input.charAt(0)) {
        case 'h':
            return Action.Hold;

        default:
            return Action.Roll;
        }
    }

}
```